# functional phpunit tests with elsticsearch

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I'm trying to find a best way to setup elasticsearch for a tests in php.

I found such a `https://github.com/zumba/elasticsearchunit` library which can make my life a bit easier, but I'm not sure how to make test instance of elasticsearch server/database, should I use same instance but separate indexes for tests (maybe with a `test_` prefix), not a best idea, as I in the actual code I'm using `https://github.com/jolicode/elastically` which has mapping in `.yaml` files where index name hardcoded, and that's mean I'll need to make separate mapping files for test env.

Is there other ways of doing it, maybe I can use separate elasticsearch node on the same instance (like a SQL database) for testing? Or maybe there are some other solutions you can share with me, I'm a bit new to elasticsearch...

For unit tests all seems to be clear, we have mock handler https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php#unit-testing-using-mock-a-elastic-client, but what to do with functional/integration tests?

Thanks in advice!

Note: my env is under docker, and I'm using https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch image.

**Updates**

I see I can create separate nodes,
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docker.html#docker-compose-file but it's not clear for me how to specify which node I want to connect???

Currently I have it like this:

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: my-app-elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

on docker side, and in PHP I have such env params:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=my-app-elasticsearch
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
```

I'm using to connect, but what should I specify as a host in case of multiple nodes, should each I simply specify separate `container_name` and use it as env variable???